# How to set outer class's variable

Tags: java, inner-classes

```
public class MySurface extends Surface View implements SurfaceHoler.Callback {
SurfaceHoler holder;
class MyThread extends Thread {
    public MyThread (SurfaceHolder holder, Context context){
        this.holder = holder;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to set "holder" which belongs to "MySurface" to the inner constructor holder but that doesn't work. I don't want to change the variable's name.

Comment: `MySurface.this.holder = ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `MyThread` is nested inside `MySurface` (*and* the `holder` argument is shadowing the `holder` instance property, see below) you have to qualify the enclosing class:

```
MySurface.this.holder = holder;
```

Inside the enclosed class `this` refers to `MyThread`.

Alternatively, you could remove `this.` altogether by renaming the argument:

```
public class MySurface extends Surface View implements SurfaceHoler.Callback {
  SurfaceHoler holder;

  class MyThread extends Thread {
    public MyThread (SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context){
      holder = surfaceHolder;
    }
  }
}
```

Also, you may find the ["Shadowing" section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html#shadowing) of the Oracle Nested Classes tutorial interesting.